# Ubuntu 22.04: Rebuilding a failed RAID 1 OS Boot drive

Tags: ubuntu, raid

I'm very new in the Linux world and I find it very appealing so I decided to buy a rackable server to use it to learn more (it's a very old Dell R710 which i found very cheap but I find it perfect for what my needs rather than going to a junkyard).

Before actually starting to use it, I'm doing a RAID 1 test on virtualbox. My plan is to have two SSDs in the server setup as RAID 1 that will have Ubuntu installed on them.

I found various guides on how to setup a raid 1 on two drives that are also os/boot drives but i didn't have much luck in finding what to do in case one of them fails, respectively how to rebuild a failed RAID 1 drive that's also an os/boot drive.

In virtualbox, i added two 10GB drives and in Ubuntu server installed, i selected:

- Custom storage layout
- Drive 1 > Use as boot device
- Drive 1 free space > add GPT partition > format [leave unformatted] & mount [/]
- Drive 2 > Add as another boot device
- Drive 2 free space > add GPT partition > format [leave unformatred] & mount [/]
- Create software raid > RAID level 1 / added both partitions

After installation, i can see this:

```
root@vm:~# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md0 : active raid1 sdb2[0] sda2[1]
      10473472 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>


root@vm:~# lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
loop0     7:0    0 111.9M  1 loop  /snap/lxd/24322
loop1     7:1    0  63.3M  1 loop  /snap/core20/1822
loop2     7:2    0  49.8M  1 loop  /snap/snapd/18357
sda       8:0    0    10G  0 disk
├─sda1    8:1    0     1M  0 part
└─sda2    8:2    0    10G  0 part
  └─md0   9:0    0    10G  0 raid1 /
sdb       8:16   0    10G  0 disk
├─sdb1    8:17   0     1M  0 part
└─sdb2    8:18   0    10G  0 part
  └─md0   9:0    0    10G  0 raid1 /
sr0      11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Now i shut down the vm, removed a disk vdi and created a new one, again of 10 GB. This will simulate the failure of one of the SDDs and replacing it with a new, empty one.

After booting again, i got this:

```
root@vm:~# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md0 : active raid1 sda2[1]
      10473472 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [_U]

unused devices: <none>
```

So what i did next is:

```
root@vm:~# sfdisk -d /dev/sda | sfdisk /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb1: Created a new partition 1 of type 'BIOS boot' and of size 1 MiB.
/dev/sdb2: Created a new partition 2 of type 'Linux filesystem' and of size 10 GiB.
```

```
root@vm:~# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 10 GiB, 10737418240 bytes, 20971520 sectors
Disk model: VBOX HARDDISK
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 087509D7-06F6-4346-BA97-7A0E0D303D9D

Device     Start      End  Sectors Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048     4095     2048   1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2   4096 20969471 20965376  10G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sdb: 10 GiB, 10737418240 bytes, 20971520 sectors
Disk model: VBOX HARDDISK
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 087509D7-06F6-4346-BA97-7A0E0D303D9D

Device     Start      End  Sectors Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048     4095     2048   1M BIOS boot
/dev/sdb2   4096 20969471 20965376  10G Linux filesystem
```

So they appear to be identical now so next, i did:

```
root@vm:~# mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdb2
```

```
root@vm:~# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md0 : active raid1 sdb2[2] sda2[1]
      10473472 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [_U]
      [================>....]  recovery = 81.2% (8508864/10473472) finish=0.1min speed=202005K/sec

unused devices: <none>
```

Now, **lsblk** looks exactly like it did when i started.

Next, I tried rebooting and going in virtualbox boot menu (F12). Here, choosing disk 1, boots just fine but choosing disk 2 complains about not having a boot loader. So i booted from disk 1 and did:

```
root@vm:~# sudo grub-install /dev/sdb
root@vm:~# sudo update-grub /dev/sdb
```

And now it seems to be booting off either drive. I also created a file before replacing the drive and this file now shows up regardless of which drive i boot from.

So it kinda works, but is this the correct way to do it?

Am i missing something that could go wrong once i setup the actual SSDs in the server?

Thank you very much and sorry for the long post but maybe someone else will find it helpful.

Comment: 1. Why did you `fdisk` your sdb? Hoe do they look before? 2. you have to `install-mbr` on `sdb` for being able to boot on sdb.

Comment: Might be offtopic, but I recommend to use BTRFS as filesystem and use its built-in RAID function. BTRFS is able to do online RAID rebuild, even for the root partition. What you always should do, install the bootloader either on both disks or use a boot device like an USB thumb drive.